# Area of quadrilateral with vectors solved in a different approach than solution

Tags: vector-spaces, self-learning, area

I have this problem and solution but I arrived at a different solution. Where am I wrong? The problem is to compute the area of the next figure:

[image]

However, I solved in a different way.

$$\overrightarrow{OA}=\langle1,2\rangle\\
\overrightarrow{OC}=\langle3,-1\rangle\\
\overrightarrow{BA}=\langle-3,-1\rangle\\
\overrightarrow{BC}=\langle-1,-4\rangle\\
\text{Area }  \triangle AOC=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 
3 & -1  \\ 
\end{vmatrix}\\
\text{Area }  \triangle ABC=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{vmatrix}
-3 & -1 \\ 
-1 & -4  \\ 
\end{vmatrix}\\
\text{Area }  \triangle AOC +\text{Area }  \triangle ABC=\frac{-1-6+12-1}{2}=\frac{4}{2}$$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: When you type $<$ and $>$ it renders them as operations however if you use $\langle$ and $\rangle$ you much cleaner look.

Comment: For the angle brackets write '\langle' and '\rangle'.

Answer (score 1):

You should see that your areas have different signs,  so you subtract one from the other . So either take the absolute value or the  or change the order of multiplication of your vectors .